# new to Xcode 7 ; simple label will not center in the simulator

Tags: uilabel, xcode7

I am taking a class online and one of the projects is to create a label.

In Xcode, I have centered it on both the vertical and horizontal axis, but when I run the simulator, and its always to the right side, not centered. I even tried it with other simulated phones.

This happens with text fields too.

I'm really not sure what is wrong, because in Xcode it is displaying correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps.

1. First Drag and drop a UILabel.
   2.Check below picture
   [image]
2. Now click on the green circle icon (right - bottom corner, second from left) shown in below image
   [image]
3. Then you can see a popup appears like below image, click on "Horizontally in Container" option.

[image]

5.Click on this red circle icon(right-bottom corner)(next to the previous green circle icon), Then you can see another popup like below image.
[image]

Now you can see a popup like this
[image]

In this Uncheck " Contrain to margins" options so it will look like this below image
[image]

6. Save and Run your code, so you can see the UILabel at center for all devices.

Output will be like 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. That worked great !!

Comment: Bangalore - you said I can accept the answer, but I do not see how to "accept the answer".